# multiple month jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to use jquery datepicker that supports multiple month. I found this link http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiMonthPopup.html.
There is a small problem in it. It display December 2999 as default date. Can anyone please suggest how can I correct it to current date. Your help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: before anything else, don't you like [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#multiple-calendars) ?

Comment: It looks like a bug with the date picker (too much recursion) - I'll take a look into it and see why it broke and will let you know when a fix is available...

Answer (score 0):

I have just committed a fix for this problem to the date picker's SVN repo:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datepicker/source/detail?r=101

Please try the example again on my site (making sure to clear your cache and get the latest version of jquery.datePickerMultiMonth.js ):

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiMonthPopup.html

Hope it helps!